# VNC - Remmina - acces remotely through the internet

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I would like to use Remmina for remote access through the internet (from Ubuntu 22.04 to 20.04).

Screen sharing already allowed, what do I enter in the input field "Remmina VNC plugin - Basic - server"? Somehow all attempts have failed such "213.34.33.111:5900", etc. What is the correct format? And do I need port forwarding in my router? How do I set up my router (port forwarding). I already know my local machine's local IP address (192.168.1....). Access from within my LAN worked already, but this is not what I require.

Thanks.

Comment: I too have been having issues getting Remmina to work on the same LAN between 20.04 and 22.04 (either way). It used to work 20.04 to 18.04 but stopped working some time ago (possibly after a kernel update - I didn't investigate further). However, I have been considering [this option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9prhMCiURyg) but not yet tried it so can't comment on it's ability.

Comment: I also tried to connect from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.04, which did not work either.

Comment: My port forwarding in my router was not set correctly, now it worked.